# wpf 3d with lots of models

Tags: wpf, performance, 3d, models

I'm making a model of human anatomy . there is about 2100 mesh and model.
I used Helix 3d toolkit to import all files into a scene but that takes a long time to import (about 20 second) and scroll and rotations are slow. and that takes 800 meg of RAM.

objects are optimized and the sum of vertics must be less that 2 million.

i don't need shadows or any special effect. but i need scroll , zoom , hit testing and ..

what format should i use for saving models? i think .obj files are slow. should i use 3ds? or xaml?

should i use 2000 modelvisual3d or one with 2000 Geometrymodel3d ?

or should i use XNA?

can i disable some features to speed things up ?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

you could try to save them as .vtk (visual toolkit) and load them with a library like three.js in a webgl canvas. (it also understands collada)

Comment: tnx . i never heard of it. I look into that. does that work perfect with wpf? can i handle events? ( I just search the web and doesn't seem to work so good with wpf) .

Comment: i think, there is better ways for windows wpf application.

Comment: im currently using this: [goxtk](http://www.goxtk.com) to open .vtk and there is really a lot included like eventhandling, lighting, etc. i thought wpf is a format. just try it!

Comment: that seems very interesting. the speed really seems good. but there is a lot of work. converting object files to .vtk and working with a framework that is not supposed to work with .Net WPF.  however have some benefits that might worth it... . tnx a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting idea to present 3D "Alive" - interactive human anatomy within WPF3D.

> what format should i use for saving models? i think .obj files are slow. should i use 3ds? or xaml?

I am sure that .obj is one of fastest. In loading it is slow but in working it is.

> should i use 2000 modelvisual3d or one with 2000 Geometrymodel3d ?

One ModelVisual3D and not 2000 Geometrymodel3d if it is possible by coding. Geometrymodel3d is for different materials. It has .Geometry, .BackMaterial and .Material.

> or should i use XNA?

XNA more faster but not interactive. You are working at application not at game.

> can i disable some features to speed things up ?

Very interesting task. At model preparing remove all back materials, made materials as simple as possible, take into account to meshes that you do not need. Provide camera rotation if it is possible. 
You can send me model and I will try to help.